# I couldn't figure out why my code doesn't pass variable back with new value?

Tags: xcode, swift3

I'm trying to figure out why when i switch to a different language it doesn't save my value that I selected in interface. I'm trying to figure out why selLangpickerView is not getting the right values when I select from pickview? here is a sample code below..

```
var langs = ["English (United States)","Chinese (China)","Chinese (Hong Kong SAR China)","Chinese (Taiwan)","English (Australia)","English   (Ireland)","English (South Africa)","English (United Kingdom)"]
var selLangpickerView: String!
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return langs.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return langs[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    switch row {
    case 0:
        selLangpickerView = "en-US"
    break
    case 1:
        selLangpickerView = "zh-CN"
        break
    case 2:
        selLangpickerView = "zh-HK"
        break
    case 3:
        selLangpickerView = "zh-TW"
        break
    case 4:
        selLangpickerView = "en-AU"
        break
    case 5:
        selLangpickerView = "en-IE"
        break
    case 6:
        selLangpickerView = "en-ZA"
        break
    case 7:
        selLangpickerView = "en-GB"
        break
    default:
        selLangpickerView = "en-US"
    }
}
```

Comment: Where `selLangpickerView` var is declared?

Comment: selLangpickerView is declare outside of these func... the variable is written like this var selLangpickerView: String!

Comment: Ok, but *still* you may need to add further details and/or code so we can help you ;) For instance, where/how do you check that `selLangpickerView` isn't being correctly updated?

Comment: switch statment that I was using to put a value to selLangpickerView = "en-US" . I thought selLangpickerView is a public value since it sits right outside of this func. It should be able to recieve new value when I set it?

Comment: Not related, but **no** `break` statements in a `switch` expression in Swift. All cases *break* by default.

Comment: are you saying if I remove the break syntax that it will allow for it work properly? it has no effect to the program if I have break or not...

Comment: Yes, the break statements have no effect. You need `break` only to ignore a case.

Comment: Is there anyway to pass data outside of the func class. It seems like variable itself isn't getting any data change when you select a new language.